# ASP.NET How to pass data from controller to view and back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im trying to sending data from controller to view and then Im trying to get data back to another action.

In my case I am trying to send a View with Model and datay(Date,Id,Room) from the controller. In the view I want to add the Name value to the submitted model and then send the whole model back to the next controller action. The problem is that in the next action only the Name value is shown and the other values are null. Does anyone know what to do?

Model im using.

```
public class ReservationModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Cas { get; set; }

        public RoomModel Room { get; set; }
    }
```

Action where from Im displaying the View with data Cas, Id and Room

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("Home/Room/Create_reservation")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReservation(DateTime date)
    {
        ReservationModel reservation = await _reservation.PrepareModel(date, _id);
        return View(reservation);
    }
```

The view where I wanna add Name value and send it whole back.

```
@model ReservationModel


<form asp- asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CreateReservation" method="post">
    <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control scan" placeholder="Name"
           asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="model-close button btn btn-primary primary-btn"
           style="width:auto;" value="Add" />

</form>
```

Action where in debuging show that reservationModel has only Name data other is null.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("Home/Room/Create_reservation")]
    public IActionResult CreateReservation([Bind("Name","Room","Cas","Id")] ReservationModel reservationModel)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: *"The problem is that in the next action only the Name value is shown and the other values are null."* - The form only has one `<input>`, and that input contains the `Name` value.  Did you simply forget to add the rest of the model to the form?

Comment: @David No i didnt. Im trying just to add `Name` value to data I have send from `CreateReservation` and in `Post` Action just save whole model to Database.

Comment: Add the other inputs and bind them like David said and they won't be null.

Comment: Ok thanks and just for curiosity. Wouldnt be better if I would save data in Controller variable and load them in the action where i need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to transfer every field in the model then you'd need inputs for every field in the model.  Currently you *only* have one input for `Name`:

```
<input required="required" type="text" class="form-control scan" placeholder="Name" asp-for="Name" />
```

Since you're only sending the `Name` value, then only the `Name` value is sent.

Based on [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983208/asp-net-how-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-and-back-to-controller?noredirect=1#comment128904902_72983208):

> Im trying just to add Name value to data I have send from CreateReservation and in Post Action just save whole model to Database.

Then there are two pieces of data you want, the `Name` and the `Id`.  Include the `Id` as another input:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
```

Then in the resulting controller action you'll have both the `Name` and the `Id`.  *Arguably* you should create a custom view model for this and not use the same model, just to avoid future confusion.  But for the sake of brevity here the same model will work.  It will just only have those two properties populated, since they're the only two you're populating.

In that controller action you would use that `Id` value to fetch the entire model from the data again.  Then you'd update *that* model instance with the `Name` which was provided by the input, and re-save that fetched model instance.

Making some assumptions, but just to illustrate:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Home/Room/Create_reservation")]
public IActionResult CreateReservation([Bind("Name","Id")] ReservationModel reservationModel)
{
    // fetch from the db
    var existingModel = _context.Reservations.Single(r => r.Id == reservationModel.Id);

    // update the value
    existingModel.Name = reservationModel.Name;

    // save
    _context.SaveChanges();

    // as an aside, this should probably be a redirect and not a view
    return View();
}
```

After all, why send *all that data* to the client and then back to the server if you're not expecting the client to do anything with it, or even see it?  Even populating hidden form fields, you're still giving the client the *ability* to edit all of the other data.  (Which means it's also worth noting here that the client *can edit the `id` value*, so you'll want to perform some kind of authorization to make sure they're not editing an object they're not allowed to edit.)

Comment: Thanks @David u helped me once agin. Yeah that is what im thinking about right know. How to pass data from one Action to another? I came up with idea to save model in Class controller as static variable. But dont know if it is the right one solution.

Comment: @fikus: No, that would definitely not be the right solution.  For cases like this, the statefulness of the operation (identifying the entity being edited) should persist through the view as a form field.  The second action shouldn't have a dependency on the first action and should be able to operate with only the inputs it receives.  And on a technical level, a `static` property would *probably* be shared by all concurrent users, so if there's ever more than one user at the same time then the whole concept of it breaks.

Comment: ok understand. And how how would you handle this problem?

Comment: @fikus: I would handle it as described in this answer.  Consider the second controller action independently, what information does it need?  It needs an identifier for the data record and it needs the inputs being edited.  Therefore the page needs to send it those values.  Therefore the first controller action needs to populate the page with those values.

Comment: I got one more idea to use `TEMPDATA` but im not shure if it would be secure enought.

Comment: @fikus: What you’re doing is trying to come up with clever ideas to make the functionality worse in order to avoid the simplest solution.  I can’t really help with that motivation.  Consider each controller action as an independent operation.  That operation requires input.  The input in this case is an identifier for the data record and the user-entered value(s).  It’s as simple as that.